Logarithmic space reduction from PATH to 2COLOR-PATH
2COLOR-PATH = {<G,s,t> | G is a 2-Colorable directed graph that has a directed path from s to t}
I need to write a logarithmic space reduction from PATH to 2COLOR-PATH (explained above). I know that I need to add vertices so that G' (the output graph) will always be 2-Colorable, and I tried to do so by adding one new node for every existing one and connecting them by an edge. But it doesn't work if G has an odd cycle. How can I fix this?

You need to put a new vertex for every edge. I.e. if $(a,b)\in E$, then you need to add a new vertex $v$, remove the edge $(a,b)$ and instead add the edges $(a,v)$ and $(v,b)$. The new graph is bipartite, thus 2-colorable and you have a path from $s$ to $t$ iff the original graph had one.

Thank you for your answer :)
just a quick clarification, why do the actions you mentioned above take logarithmic space?
